# "No Devices Syncing" in menu bar

Tags: macos, mac, data-synchronization

Previously in the menu bar when I click on the "Refresh" icon it use to say Sync Now and now it says No Devices Syncing.

Is this feature now obsolete due to MobileMe not available anymore?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct, this was part of MobileMe and is no longer supported.